Non-empty infinite intersection of nested closed subsets of a sequentially compact space
The question is as follows: Suppose that $X$ is a sequentially compact space X and we are given a nested sequence $V_1 \supseteq V_2 \supseteq V_3 \supseteq \dots$ of non-empty closed subsets of $X$. Prove that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n \neq \emptyset$ (note that the space is not metric).
This is my solution: Let $(V_n)$ be a sequence of closed nested sets. Since $V_{n+1} \subseteq V_n$, we have that our sequence is monotonically decreasing. Hence, its subsequence $(V_{n_k})$ must converge to the same limit as the main sequence. Since $X$ is sequentially compact, the subsequence $(V_{n_k})$ (and hence $(V_{n})$) must approach some element $x$ where $x \in X$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$. This implies that $x \in V_\infty$ and hence  $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n \neq \emptyset$.
My doubts stem from the fact that the subsequence of sets must converge to a point, which is not possible. However, in this case, it think it could be allowed. I am not sure, though. Should I say that $\{x\} = V_\infty$ to circumvent this possible problem? But would that say that the subsequence converges to $x$? Is my proof correct? Any feedback is appreciated!

Your proof attempt does not make sense: convergence of subsets would only be defined, if you had a topology on the set of these subsets. But here you have only a topology on $X$.

Oh right, I didn't know! Thank you for mentioning it.

As the $V_i, i\in\Bbb N$ are not empty, each contains at least one element, let us call it $u_i$. We have just defined $(u_n), n\in\Bbb N$ as a sequence of elements of $X$. That sequence must have a convergent subsequence converging to a point. Let us call that sequence $u_{n_k}$ and take $l = \lim_{k\to\infty}{u_{n_k}}$
Let us consider an arbitrary $N\in\Bbb N$, for $n_k \geq N, V_{n_k}\subseteq V_N$, so $u_{n_k}\in V_N$. We have a convergent sequence in the closed set $V_N$: the limit is also an element of the set. As $N$ was arbitrary, we have shown: $\forall N\in\Bbb N, l\in V_N$, which is enough to prove that $l \in \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}{V_n}$.
So we have finally shown: $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}{V_n}\ne\emptyset$.

In your proposed solution, you only used the $V_n$ subsets. As what we know is the sequentially compacity of $X$, we have to find a sequence of elements of $X$, the reason why I have taken one element in each $V_n$.

Another way to see Serge Ballesta's solution: if $l\not\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}V_n$, choose $N\in\mathbb N$ with $l\not\in V_N$. Then $V_N^{\mathrm C}$ is an open neighborhood of $l$ that misses all $u_n$ for $n\geq N$; contradiction.
